# Vertical centring images with known height in div with variable height, allowing images to overflow div above and below

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to find a method of vertical centring images in a div of uncertain height, allowing the images to overflow the div when their heigh is larger than the containing div's. The div contains a randomly selected slogan which can be of various different lengths (and of course if the browser window width is small it may make even a short slogan run over two lines).

I have shown the problem in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4effect/gko2b3er/4/). I have tried every method of pure css that I can think of (including negative margins, pseudo elements and transforms), but they only seem to work when the height of the containing div can be guessed or known. That suggests that the only way to achieve what I want is using javascript (jquery?) to establish the height of the div and then use that to give the images either a negative or a positive margin, but I don't know how to achieve that.

```
<div class="slogan">
    <img src="http://www.placebear.com/150/150" alt="pic 1" class="tsimg-left"> <img src="http://www.placebear.com/150/150" alt="pic 2" class="tsimg-right">SLOGAN OF VARIOUS LENGTHS, SOME ONE LINE, SOME THREE OR FOUR</div>

.slogan {
background-color: rgba(255, 100, 0, 0.3);
text-align:center; 
display:block;
width:80%;
position:relative;
float:none;
padding:2em; 
margin:0.5em auto 1em auto;
box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
border-radius: 0.8em;
z-index:6;
}
.tsimg-left, .tsimg-right, .tsimg-centre {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 1em;
    height:150px;
    border-radius:50%;
}
.tsimg-left {
    float: left;
}
.tsimg-right {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: Look http://jsfiddle.net/molo4nik11/gko2b3er/7/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, @mutant_america, but the problem I am having is not the vertical centring, it's combining vertical centring with allowing the images to overflow the div. This is the effect I am trying to achieve: [take a look](http://jsfiddle.net/e4effect/gko2b3er/8/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weirdly there is a way to achieve this.
This is probably what you need:
HTML:

```
<div class="slogan">
    <img src="http://www.placebear.com/150/150" alt="pic 1" class="tsimg-left" />
    <span>SLOGAN OF VARIOUS LENGTHS, SOME ONE OR TWO LINES<br/>Slogan of various lengths
    SLOGAN OF VARIOUS LENGTHS, SOME ONE OR TWO LINES<br/>Slogan of various lengths
    SLOGAN OF VARIOUS LENGTHS, SOME ONE OR TWO LINES<br/>Slogan of various lengths<br/>Slogan of various lengths
    SLOGAN OF VARIOUS LENGTHS, SOME ONE OR TWO LINES<br/>Slogan of various lengths</span>
    <img src="http://www.placebear.com/150/150" alt="pic 2" class="tsimg-right" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    padding-top:2em;
}
.slogan {
  background-color: rgba(255, 100, 0, 0.3);
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2.5em auto 1em auto;
  z-index: 6;
  line-height: 100%;
}
.slogan img,
.slogan span {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.slogan span {
    width:250px;
}
.tsimg-left, .tsimg-right {
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
}
.tsimg-left {
    left:5%;
}
.tsimg-right {
    right:5%;
}
```

and [Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/gko2b3er/10/)

I've changed markup order, and made all children of slogan to be displayed as inline-block elements. Another thing to do is to restrict width of your text inside the div, which I wrapped in span tag (I think this is valid html now). And finally used a vertical aligning method, utilizing absolute positioning, transforms and top property.

Let me know if this is what you are after.

PS. No JavaScript needed

Comment: An excellent solution @robjez. It works well and does the trick. I had also tried transforms but my version didn't work properly. The only thing I would change in your solution is to give the <span> a left and right margin equivalent to the image size rather than specifying a fixed width. Many thanks for finding the solution! It has been driving me mad for a few days! And, as you say: no JavaScript! Excellent.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** (Previous method didn't seem to work)

Use this:

```css
.slogan {
    display: flex;
    background-color: silver;
    text-align: center;
}
.slogan > p {
    align-self: center;
    color: red;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#pic1 {
    display: inline-block;
    align-self: center;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin: auto;
}
#pic2 {
    align-self: center;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 750px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="slogan">
    <img src="http://www.placebear.com/150/150" alt="pic 1" id="pic1"></img><p>Here goes some text!</p>
    <img src="http://www.placebear.com/150/150" alt="pic 2" id="pic2"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Aramil. Again the issue is that I have no problem containing the images inside the div (I could even do that by setting them as background images and allowing them to fill the height of the div), the problem is trying to allow them to overflow the div whilst positioning the centre of each image at the vertical middle of the div. (If the div height happens to be larger than the image height, they will sit inside it.) [Take a look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4effect/gko2b3er/9/) to see the effect I am trying to achieve